# Fixpoint on Types

Tags: types, coq

I want to create a function(`fixpoint` to be specific) in Coq that takes two types as input and tells whether they are same or not. The signature of this function can be given as

```
Fixpoint areSame (X1 X2 : Type) : bool
```

Please let me know if it even possible or not.

I create a custom datatype as following

```
Inductive State : Type :=
  | state : forall X:Type, X -> State.
```

Now i want to compare any two given strings.
Lets say i want to compare two states formed as following,

```
state bool true , state bool false
```

In order to do so, i must first confirm both states are defined with type `bool`, and then compare values with equivalence defined on `bool`.

All help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do so in the term language (Gallina), because the term `Type` is open, and so for instance you cannot pattern match on its elements.

---

I believe a solution to your problem is to define an inductive datatype of descriptions of types of states, along with their interpretation in terms of `Type`:

```
Inductive StateType : Type :=
| Bool
.

Definition typeOfStateType (t : StateType) : Type :=
  match t with
  | Bool -> bool
  end.

Inductive State : Type :=
| state : forall (st : StateType), typeOfStateType st -> State
.
```

Comment: The reason I used 

`state : forall X:Type, X -> State.`

is so that I have some instance of any arbitrary type contained in State.

The root problem to begin with was to come up with a general representation for a Set, so I have 

`Inductive typedSet {X:Type} :=
  | cset : (X -> bool) -> typedSet.`

So basically to create any set,
I need a deterministic function of signature

`State -> bool`

One can easily deduce why I need Type, to allow any possible set.